# Deployment of Go App + Vue.js on Heroku using docker image

Tags: docker, go, heroku, vue.js, axios

I am trying to deploy an app https://github.com/valasek/timesheet on Heroku using a docker image.
App has a go backend (negroni/gorilla) and Vue.js/Vuetify.js on the frontend and is using PostgreSQL persistence.

I am stuck on deployment. I do not know how to debug, how to show the command line output, what is failing ... and any help highly appreciated.

Relevant Dockerfile - https://github.com/valasek/timesheet/blob/master/Dockerfile

Here are the steps I am doing:

```
> docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t timesheet:latest .
Successfully tagged timesheet:latest
...

> heroku container:push timesheet:latest --app timesheet-cloud
...
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/timesheet-cloud/timesheet]
...
Your image has been successfully pushed. You can now release it with the 'container:release' command.

> heroku container:release timesheet --app timesheet-cloud
Releasing images timesheet to timesheet-cloud... done

> heroku ps -a timesheet-cloud
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 971h 8m (97%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

No dynos on ⬢ timesheet-cloud

> heroku logs --app timesheet-cloud
2019-02-15T08:33:49.373221+00:00 app[api]: Deployed timesheet (709022e100f9) by user <email-reducted>@gmail.com
2019-02-15T08:33:49.373221+00:00 app[api]: Release v20 created by user <email-reducted>@gmail.com
2019-02-15T08:34:43.901070+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=timesheet-cloud.herokuapp.com request_id=4c21eb79-5344-4d40-b341-8977128c873f fwd="195.250.152.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-02-15T08:34:44.842322+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=timesheet-cloud.herokuapp.com request_id=b66caaee-880a-46a0-918b-e778a49334f4 fwd="195.250.152.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-02-15T08:34:54.865321+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=timesheet-cloud.herokuapp.com request_id=d5af6aa7-0279-4f0e-a4cc-0f9e8682ec2f fwd="195.250.152.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-02-15T08:34:55.158317+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=timesheet-cloud.herokuapp.com request_id=2d69f4b5-9015-48de-9314-c493703818d1 fwd="195.250.152.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Have you tried to deploy same app on AWS?

Comment: How does it solve Heroku problem? No, I did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to happen because Heroku does not detect any endpoint for your application (binded on port 3000 by default).

Heroku attributes your app a dynamic port, and put the port value on the env variable named `$PORT`.

Your app have to use the value specified by Heroku in this variable and listen for incoming connections on it, because that is where Heroku will forward connections.

The variable has to be read when the app starts:
https://help.heroku.com/PPBPA231/how-do-i-use-the-port-environment-variable-in-container-based-apps

You can check current env variables on your app using `heroku run printenv`

(I see you are using Viper, that should handle env variables. However they say in their documentation that when from env, it is case sensitive, maybe that could explain why it does not work for you: https://github.com/spf13/viper#working-with-environment-variables)

Comment: This is probably the reason - This appears to happen because Heroku does not detect any endpoint for your application, but not due to PORT variable. I am aware of this and I tested locally that app listens on the correct port if PORT env variable is set. If not it falls back to default port 300 from timesheet.yaml config file.

Comment: @StanislavValášek can you confirm you tested locally the PORT env var using the `docker-entrypoint.sh` file to start the app / or directly with a built container ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Jonathan Muller. Solved!
GUI is running on https://timesheet-cloud.herokuapp.com.

1. On Heroku DB connection and PORT string should be read from the environment variables

   - [DATABASE_URL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#create-new-db)
   - [PORT](https://help.heroku.com/PPBPA231/how-do-i-use-the-port-environment-variable-in-container-based-apps)

Updated was file [timesheet.yaml](https://github.com/valasek/timesheet/blob/master/server/timesheet.yaml).

2. BaseUrl in Axios is set to '' so Axios is using relative API URLs, which works. Fixed in file [axiosSettings.js](https://github.com/valasek/timesheet/blob/master/client/src/api/axiosSettings.js).

Before the command `heroku run printenv` returned:

```
panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused
```

Now I am getting:

```
Running printenv on ⬢ timesheet-cloud... up, run.1962 (Free)
Feb 15 16:22:34.186 [INFO] config file /timesheet.yaml
Feb 15 16:22:34.197 [INFO] connecting to DB postgres://user:hash@ec2-54-235-68-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dbname
Feb 15 16:22:34.246 [INFO] connected to DB postgres://user:hash@ec2-54-235-68-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dbname
```

Comment: Your server seems fine now. Is `const port = process.env.PORT || 3000` JavaScript code ? The JS should have port set to https port `443` when in production because the backend port is not the same port as the proxy facing internet used by Heroku.

`process.env.PORT || 3000` in the JS should be used only for dev mode when there is no proxy involved

Comment: Yes. It is JS code. When I set `baseURL: ''` it is working. I will experiment with `443` and post it here. Thank you for your informative answers and links.

Comment: I think with empty baseURL it uses the current URL of your website, and as your website is served through https, it uses the port 443 by default. Glad to know it is working, your project looks good. Good luck